# Calling A Cell Whose Row is the Contents of Another Cell

Tags: excel, formulas

I want to call cell A???.  The value of B1 is "100".  I want to call A100 by using that value in B1.  So how do I generate a reference to CELL A**value of B1**?  I need to do it like this because I want this to be dynamic, so I can simply change the contents of B1 and have this formula now call to cell A200, for example.

Any help would be much appreciated.

-Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple ways of doing this:

```
=INDIRECT("A"&B1)

=OFFSET(A1,B1-1,0,1,1)

=INDEX(A:A,B1)
```

**Update in Response to Comment by Scott**

How to choose between the options above:

**Indirect:** Indirect leads to recalculation each time a cell is updated in the sheet and is a "heavy" function. However, you can construct the address dynamically (at least the row number). This was closest to your question and **easiest to understand** which could be important in case you have only one or two such formulae in the sheet.

**Index**: Index offers great **performance** as long as the range you need to choose from is defined. It works in both directions (Horizontal and Vertical) in at least recent versions of Excel. It is limited in a way that it can only refer to one cell and not a range unlike the other methods. It is a safe bet even if you insert or delete rows and columns from the selection range. The formula will adjust itself.

**Offset:** Offset offers greater flexibility at a cost. Excel recalculates this formula every time any cell in the sheet is updated leading to the file becoming "Heavy". The benefit it offers is **flexibility** in the size of the range that you need for further calculation. For example you could write a formula in A1 `=SUM(OFFSET(B2,A2-2,B1-2,A3,C1))` to get the sum of a dynamic range starting at Row specified in A2, Column in B1, Width in A3 and Height in C1.

**Update in Response of Needing Reference to Another Sheet**

My personal preference in this case is Offset since it allows the original cell to be in another sheet, or even another Workbook!

```
=OFFSET(Sheet2!A1,B1-1,0,1,1)
```

**Update in response to the more complex problem stated by OP in comments**

The following formula will solve the complex problem stated by OP
=COUNTIF(OFFSET(INDIRECT(A2&"!Z"&C3),0,0,C4-C3+1,1),C5)+COUN‌​TIF(OFFSET(INDIRECT(‌​A2&"!F"&C3),0,0,C4-C‌​3+1,1),C5)

**Explanation**

Indirect formula identifies the starting cell on another sheet.

Offset uses this and identifies the entire range to compare.

Countif uses the output of Offset and counts the cells that match C5.

This is done twice for Columns Z and F on sheet specified by A2 in current sheet. There is always hope!

Comment: FWIW: Indirect and Offset are volatile functions, in that they will re calculate every time Excel calculates even if the underlying data has not changed.  While the INDEX is not and will only re calculate if the underlying data changes.

Comment: Thanks, Scott.  I found something on Google yesterday about using the INDEX function, but couldn't get it to work.  Today it worked.  I think INDIRECT may be the way to go for me here.  But I may be giving up on going this route because I actually have to call another SHEET with this formula and I could have already written this spreadsheet ten times by now by just typing in directly what I need.  But maybe it's something I can play around with later.

Comment: Here's what I have.  Let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: (Pressing ENTER posts these comments; NOT cool) :)    =SUMPRODUCT(((--INDIRECT("'"&A2&"'!"&"Z100:Z199"))=C$5)*((--INDIRECT("'"&A2&"'!"&"F100:F199"))=""))   The name of the SHEET I'm calling to is in CELL A2.  *ON* that SHEET, I want to call the range of Z100:Z199 (and later in the formula F100:F199 as you see here).  I'm also referencing cell C5 on the SHEET I'm ON.  I'm asking to display how many times in cells Z100:Z199 and F100:F199 is there a value that matches what's in C5 on the current sheet.  The values of "100" and "199" are in CELLS C3 and C4 respectively on my current sheet...

Comment: ...continued--- I would like to be able to change the values of 100 and/or 199 in C3 or C4 and have this formula change dynamically.  So this is long and complicated, but if there's any hope, that would be great.  This formula I posted works as far as calling to the other sheet (whose name could be changed if necessary), but I'd like it to call to 100:199 or whatever I put in C3 and C4.  Make sense?

Comment: Chris try this instead. Edited some typos: =COUNTIF(OFFSET(INDIRECT(A2&"!Z"&C3),0,0,C4-C3+1,1),C5)+COUNTIF(OFFSET(INDIRECT(A2&"!F"&C3),0,0,C4-C3+1,1),C5)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the non-Volatile INDEX:

```
=INDEX(A:A,B1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula:

```
=OFFSET(A1,B1-1,0)
```

The first parameter is an "anchor" cell, the second is vertical offset from it and the third is horizontal offset from it.

As anchor cell you may choose an **arbitrary** cell and then use the `vertical` and `horizontal` offsets from it.

Comment: Please consider to accept and upvote the answer(-s) which was useful for you.